# Is it possible to rename a TFS workspace?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Is it possible to reaname a TFS workspace? If it is, how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is your workspace, In Visual Studio, File, Source Control, Workspaces...  Select the workspace you want to rename and press "Edit".  Then edit the name and press OK.

Answer (score 4):

in the Visual Studio Command Prompt type

```
tf workspace /newname:YourNewWorkspaceName YourActualWorkspaceName /noprompt
```

(alternatively you can use the standard cmd line but then you need to locate tf.exe)

Comment: I had to add the " /collection:MyCollection" parameter.  Note.....this causes alot of file-locking issues for me.  So my advice would be to : 1. reboot machine.  2. do NOT open VS 3. run the code above.  4.  reboot again 5.  try to "get latest" and make sure you don't get voodoo errors.  it may be overkill, BUT once I hit a file lock issue (maybe because I had VS open) I had to spend 25 minutes...getting it right before it was renamed AND a tfs-get-latest didn't throw strange errrors.